# forge.request.ajax post data as json

Tags: ajax, request, trigger.io, forge

I have begun using trigger.io to make our jQuery mobile web app as a native build. The web app in its current form uses a plugin called [janky.post](http://saunter.org/janky.post/) to make cross-domain posts, submitting the data in json format - which is what our PHP based API expects.

I have started using `forge.request.ajax` instead in the native build which works for all the forms in the app except for one. The request doesn't appear to be submitted as a json encoded object, rather it is a standard $_POST array. This is not so much of a problem as I can modify the API to detect this, but the because the data submitted is multidimensional the method seems to be malforming the array, so that it is not structured as expected.

How do I correct this behavior in order to get the output I desire? Is there anyway for me to force a json submission for the form? If yes, are there any drawbacks to doing this? Would it prevent me from adding file uploads to this form submission in the future?

**Example:**

To expand on what I mean the process is as follows. On submit, the controllers format the form data into json and pass it to ajax method like so:

```
window.forge.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'foo.com/bar',
    data: data,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function( response ) {
        /* code omitted */
    });
});
```

The reason for this is because some of the data in the post doesn't come directly from the form itself, but is provided by additional models. The structure of `data` being posted is as follows:

```
{
    id: '23',
    date: '2012-08-30 00:00:00',
    name: 'Foo',
    items: [{
        description: 'Bar',
        quantity: '1',
        price: '20'
    }]
}
```

But when it is received as an array by our PHP based API the structure is as follows:

```
array(
    'id' => '23'
    'date' => '2012-08-30 00:00:00',
    'name' => 'Foo',
    'items' => array(
        0 => array( 'description' => 'Bar' ),
        1 => array( 'quantity' => '1' ),
        2 => array( 'price' => '20' )
    )
)
```

As you can see, each field that corresponds to a single item in the items array has been changed into its own array which is wrong, it should be:

```
 items = array(
     0 => array(
         'description' => 'Bar',
         'quantity' => '1',
         'price' '20'
     )
 )
```

Comment: Am I wrong when I interpret: items: [{ description: 'Bar', quantity: '1', price: '20' }] as... an array with one item?

Comment: No you're right, that is an array with one item. Like wise if it had two items it would be:

`items:[{description: 'Bar', quantity:'1', price:'20'}, {description: 'Hello', quantity:'2', price:'10'}]`

Comment: Does the "network" option in Catalyst provided any more request details?

Comment: Inspecting the network through Catalyst at the request payload the data submitted when urldecoded looks like this:

`data[id]=23&data[date]=2012-08-30&data[name]=Foo&data[items][][description]=Bar&data[items][][quantity]=1&data[items][][price]=20`

As you can see for items it is creating a new array index for each field, rather than creating a new array for each item as: `data[items][0][description]=Bar&data[items][0][quantity]=1&data[items][0][price]=20`

Comment: Ok I managed to fix the code my end in a slightly hacky way by creating a temp indexed array for the items when the model returns the items data, and passing that instead. 

`var tempItems = {}; for ( var i = 0; i < items.length; i++ ) { tempItems[i] = items[i];}` 

Not the most ideal solution as this is in my opinion a bug in how JSON is parsed by forge.request.ajax when dealing with multidimensional structures. Would prefer to see this fixed in the method.

Comment: It looks like you've found a bug in the way we encode post data, a simple workaround until we get it fixed would be to wrap your data object in JSON.stringify, which will mean the data is sent as a JSON string rather than query string encoded (which I think is what you originally wanted).

Comment: Thank you Connor. Look forward to the fix. Great job on Trigger.IO by the way, you guys are building an amazing product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Connorhd said, this was a bug in how we encoded objects inside arrays: I've fixed now - will deploy by end of week. Sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: No problem James, thank you for the feedback and for the quick fix! Happy to have contributed a little bit to a fantastic project. Any plans to open source?

Comment: Yes: we need build out some other services and products first to protect ourselves as a company, but we're planning to gradually open source more as we go.